# Selecting Maven Profiles in Intellij 14

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, profile

I'm using intellij 14 and have the maven projects window open.

Why are there 2 different kinds of checkboxes?  If you select the checkbox once, it will leave a white check.  If you select it again, it will change the checkbox to gray.  Whats the difference?

I also want to know how to tell a specific module (not the entire project) to use a particular maven profile that is only available to that module.

I have been unable to find this information on intellij's site.
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three possible states for a profile:

1. Disabled:

   [image: Disabled]
2. Active:

   [image: Active]
3. Active by Default:

   [image]

The last one is activated by setting something like this in your `pom.xml`

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

Comment: Thanks, so what happens if I were to for example mark both "dev", and some other profile as active when they both exist in the POM?

Comment: It's entirely possible to have >1 profile marked as active, so there should be no issues, so whatever each profile is configured to do will be combined.

Comment: I think I'm still missing something (sorry if that is the case).  Say I have 20 projects imported, and for 19 of them I want them to build using dependencies that are part of the "dev" profile, but for the 20th one I want to run an "intellijSpecific" profile instead of the "active by default" "dev" profile.  It does not appear intellij is capable of doing this as it appears we are targeting all projects imported instead of the profile for a particular project?  Additionally, does the "active" profile override the "active by default" profile?